# (Intel XDK) can´t use a 'Post' form to use a PHP function

Tags: php, intel-xdk

I developed an HTML5 application. I want to use it on Intel XDK and all works fine with one exception, a Form with  a 'POST' action to use a PHP function which saves a chosen image into a application folder.
When I try to use it I get the following error:

```
Cannot POST /http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/XXXXXXXXX/Documents/Proyectos/centerinformaticapp/www/guardarImg.php
```

How can I make it work?
Can anybody give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Use of Ajax or XHR.

```
var formData=$('#formId').serialize();   
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          console.log("success");
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "http://yoursite.com/abc.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send(formData);//your post data
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and worked once, now I getting a 404 for xhttp.status and I can´t upload images anymore, do you know waht can I dot to make it work everytime?

Comment: where did u try it? ON device or emulator?

Comment: On emulator, I don´t have a cellphone to test by now

Comment: I can make it work changing: $('#formId').serialize(); for new FormData(document.getElementById('formId')); but only works as a web page and not in Intel XDK