# Error 404 for Ajax request in Intel XDK to call a php

Tags: php, ajax, intel-xdk

I need in my app a function to choose a image and save it in a app's folder, I did a form and a php that achieves what I want without Intel XDK but with Intel XDK I made it with ajax and worked just ONE time and now I get 404 for "xhttp.status" everytime I test the app in the emulator.

This is my javascript code:

```
function guardarImagen(){
    var formData=$('#formulario').serialize();   
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
         alert("Subida de Imagen exitosa");
      }else{
        alert(xhttp.readyState + " & " + xhttp.status);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "guardarImg.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhttp.send(formData);
  }
```

What can I do to make sure that works becuase I saw in other posts that XDK sometimes have issues in the emulator but installed in phone all works fine.

Also, I don´t have a phone (Android) to test.
I did this: [(Intel XDK) can´t use a 'Post' form to use a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218168/intel-xdk-can%C2%B4t-use-a-post-form-to-use-a-php-function/39218702#39218702)

My code is fine?
What else can I do?

Thank you all.

Comment: Try to set full URL instead of the php file only on xhttp.open(...